# jQuery changes select option next previous buttons AND Load content

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I need some help about this jQuery problem. I need something like this:

http://pastebin.com/vV5KEQfM

What I need Previous and Next buttons that works!

The problem is not the code for buttons. I found this for buttons:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#selectField").val($("#selectField > option:selected").next().val());
})

$("#prev").click(function() {
    $("#selectField").val($("#selectField > option:selected").prev().val());
})
```

**It woks but it won't show content of DIV just changing the option in select menu..**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the value using .val() doesn't trigger the *change* event. You need to trigger it manually using `$('#selectField').change()`.

This should work:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    $("#selectField").val($("#selectField > option:selected").next().val());
    $('#selectField').change();
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
    $("#selectField").val($("#selectField > option:selected").prev().val());
    $('#selectField').change();
});
```